# How can I copy the contents of one file to another using Ruby's file methods?

Tags: ruby

I want to copy the contents of one file to another using Ruby's file methods.

How can I do it using a simple Ruby program using file methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing that using ruby file operation methods :

```
source_file, destination_file = ARGV 
script = $0

input = File.open(source_file)  
data_to_copy = input.read()  # gather the data using read() method

puts "The source file is #{data_to_copy.length} bytes long"

output = File.open(destination_file, 'w')
output.write(data_to_copy)  # write up the data using write() method

puts "File has been copied"

output.close()
input.close()
```

You can also use `File.exists?` to check if the file exists or not. This would return a boolean true if it does!!

Comment: You might explain the purpose of: `script = $0`, also protect against reading a file bigger than memory.

Answer (score 21):

There is a very handy method for this - the `IO#copy_stream method` - see the output of `ri copy_stream`

Example usage:

```
File.open('src.txt') do |f|
  f.puts 'Some text'
end

IO.copy_stream('src.txt', 'dest.txt')
```

Comment: Why not use the block version of `open` that makes sure the file is closed even in the case of an exception?

Comment: Even better: why not use `File.write('src.txt', "Some text\n")`?

Comment: @DNNX From the docs, `File.write` writes `string`. If the contents are other than plain text files, such as images, it won't work. You'd have to use `binread` and `binwrite` instead.

Answer (score 13):

For those that are interested, here's a variation of the `IO#copy_stream`, `File#open + block` answer(s) (written against ruby 2.2.x, 3 years too late).

```
copy = Tempfile.new
File.open(file, 'rb') do |input_stream|
  File.open(copy, 'wb') do |output_stream|
    IO.copy_stream(input_stream, output_stream)
  end
end
```

Comment: Just commenting that the `b` indicates `binmode` ([binary file mode](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)).

Answer (score 8):

As a precaution I would recommend using buffer unless you can guarantee whole file **always** fits into memory:

```
    File.open("source", "rb") do |input|
      File.open("target", "wb") do |output|
        while buff = input.read(4096)
          output.write(buff)
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: +1 Very correct. Even in today's world with multi-gigabyte RAM, it's important to pay attention to the amount being pulled in. Nothing like taking a big server to its knees after trying to read a file that was bigger than available memory. It's hard to defend such an action in an enterprise. I would recommend using nested `File.open` blocks to automatically close the files though.

Comment: Why not use the block version of `open` that makes sure the file is closed even in the case of an exception?

Comment: @Qerub Because it depends on how you are going to process such exception. Closing stream is not always right thing to do, especially when two files are affected.

Comment: This is pretty much duplicating the `IO.copy_stream` method. Even the buffer is not needed as ruby internally uses `16 * 1024` (16Kb) buffer for the  `IO.copy_stream`, [link to internal function in the source code where this buffer is created and read + write happens in a loop](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/f2d18484417fdc6e9ae4970fed7eda0de1027e91/io.c#L10692)

Answer (score 4):

Here my implementation

```
class File
  def self.copy(source, target)
    File.open(source, 'rb') do |infile|
      File.open(target, 'wb') do |outfile2|
        while buffer = infile.read(4096)
          outfile2 << buffer
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
File.copy sourcepath, targetpath
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast and concise way to do it.

```
# Open first file, read it, store it, then close it
input = File.open(ARGV[0]) {|f| f.read() }

# Open second file, write to it, then close it
output = File.open(ARGV[1], 'w') {|f| f.write(input) }
```

An example for running this would be.

```
$ ruby this_script.rb from_file.txt to_file.txt
```

This runs ***this_script.rb*** and takes in two arguments through the command-line. The first one in our case is ***from_file.txt*** (text being copied from) and the second argument ***second_file.txt*** (text being copied to).

Answer (score 1):

You can *also* use `File.binread` and `File.binwrite` if you wish to hold onto the file contents for a bit. (Other answers use an instant `copy_stream` instead.)

If the contents are **other than plain text files**, such as images, using basic `File.read` and `File.write` won't work.

```
temp_image = Tempfile.new('image.jpg')
actual_img = IO.binread('image.jpg')
IO.binwrite(temp_image, actual_img)
```

Source: [binread](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-binread), 
[binwrite](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-binwrite).